# Animating only works for "body" and "html"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

What I'm doing is kind of complex but I think there just has to be a better way.

[Here's](https://codepen.io/connorv/pen/RjdJGV?editors=1100) a CodePen with my web functionality.

the key to this functionality is in this script right here:

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('body, html').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
        }, 1000);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

To kind of overview what this is doing, when specific anchor link is clicked under div `nav` the entire `body` and `html` elements are horizontally scrolled to a different section of the page, with the goal being a one page site that still has the content of 3 pages with smooth animations.

It would be ideal if I could target a different element to scroll rather than `body, html` but I'm not sure why the entire script seems to fail (without console error) if I try to select anything else. The issue with the current set up is that the entire page scrolls instead of just the container with the content, I'm obviously doing something wrong in this regard.

So, the second script below it is really just a bandaid for the first one, based off of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/EzXub/263/) simple script that kind of places the rest of the page in a fixed positioning, but only for one axis. So that the content stays centered. In practice, this is only emulating the functionality I'm looking for & so the performance is awful.

Comment: `bind()` is deprecated in jQuery 3. Use `on()`.

Comment: @isherwood the "second script below" is in the JS section of the codepen

Comment: There is an extra `</div>` that is not associated with a opening `<div>` on Line 65.